# Is there a rule for using adverbial clauses/phrases directly after conjunctions?

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, adverbial-phrases, fronting

> I went to the park **because I needed to clear my head**, *and* **when it was morning**, I returned home.

In this sentence, we see two subordinate clauses and two independent clauses.

The two subordinate clauses are 'because I needed to clear my head' and 'when it was morning'.
The two independent clauses are 'I went to the park' and 'I returned home'.

However, the second subordinate clause—which follows a coordinating conjunction ('and')—is fronted. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any rule that dissuades fronting immediately after a conjunction, or do we treat it like any normal sentence? (This is a broader expansion on a [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299530/can-a-subordinate-clause-be-fronted-in-a-that-clause) I had.)

Here are two more examples, each of which is different.

> It was true *that* **in the morning**, his head would be clear.
>
> **In the beginning**, his head was cloudy, *but* **in the end**, he felt rejuvenated.

Answer (score 1):

> I went to the park because I needed to clear my head, and **when it was morning**, I returned home.

It is perfectly OK to front an adverbial clause, even in a sentence like yours.  If you front an adverbial clause, it's normal to put a comma after it, as you have done. When the fronted adverbial clause ends up in the middle of a sentence, it needs an extra comma before it, so it is delimited at both ends by a comma. The comma before **and** is optional, so we can simply more that comma one word later:

> I went to the park because I needed to clear my head and, **when it was morning**, I returned home.

[This article](https://www.margieholdscourt.com/commas-for-an-adverb-clause-in-the-middle/) explains this. The same applies to the other two sentences:

> It was true that, **in the morning**, his head would be clear.

> In the beginning, his head was cloudy but, **in the end**, he felt rejuvenated.

Comment: I agree with the use of commas in the subordinate clauses. However, I have seen writers omit the comma after 'and' and 'but' on many occasions. For example, 'I drove to the beach, and when I arrived, I saw the sun rising from the sea.' This appears to be a matter of style, although I think your version is more appropriate for 'that' clauses.

Comment: Adding to this, I would like to note that my question relates more to the flexibility of subordinate clauses when choosing where to position (specific rules). Your question does address this, albeit indirectly.